# Are there different versions of the Adam Sub8 Subwoofer?

Tags: subwoofer

I own a pair of the lovely Adam A7X. Now I'd like to extend its lower range capabilities by buying an Adam Sub8 on eBay. The seller states that it is from 2008. But now I've noticed that the back panel with the connectors is located on the bottom of the subwoofer while the current pictures on the Adam website show the panel on the top.

[image: Sub8 from 2008 on eBay]
[image: Current Adam Sub8 Model]

So I asked myself if there are any other differences on those two Sub8 versions? I know there is an Adam Sub10 and Sub10 Mk II but AFAIK there's no newer Sub8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being in contact with the ADAM Support it turned out Adam mixed the pictures up with the panel of the Sub10.

Indeed there have been some revisions of the Sub8 but the changes where small enough not to be reflected in the product description.